# Why my QFileSystemModel QModelIndex couldn't get child node infomation?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qfilesystemmodel

I am learn about Model/View architecture in pyqt, but when i follow the [Using model indexes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#using-model-indexes) instruction and try to write a demo in pyqt5 style.The QModelIndex couldn't get child node information?

The code:

```py
class DemoB(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

    def on_clicked(self, checked):
        model = QFileSystemModel()
        model.setRootPath(QDir.homePath())
        parentIndex = model.index(QDir.homePath())
        print(parentIndex.data() )
        print(parentIndex, model.rowCount(parentIndex), QDir.homePath())
        for row in range(model.rowCount(parentIndex)):
            index = model.index(row, 0, parentIndex)
            print(index, index.data())
```

The result:

> [image]

My folder:

> [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Explanation:

As the docs([1](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#caching-and-performance), [2](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#setRootPath)) points out:

> #### Caching and Performance
>
> QFileSystemModel will not fetch any
>   files or directories until setRootPath() is called. This will prevent
>   any unnecessary querying on the file system until that point such as
>   listing the drives on Windows.
>
> Unlike QDirModel, QFileSystemModel uses a separate thread to populate
>   itself so it will not cause the main thread to hang as the file system
>   is being queried. Calls to rowCount() will return 0 until the model
>   populates a directory.
>
> QFileSystemModel keeps a cache with file information. The cache is
>   automatically kept up to date using the QFileSystemWatcher.

---

> #### QModelIndex QFileSystemModel::setRootPath(const QString &newPath)
>
> Sets
>   the directory that is being watched by the model to newPath by
>   installing a file system watcher on it. Any changes to files and
>   directories within this directory will be reflected in the model.
>
> If the path is changed, the rootPathChanged() signal will be emitted.
>
> **Note: This function does not change the structure of the model or
>   modify the data available to views. In other words, the "root" of the
>   model is not changed to include only files and directories within the
>   directory specified by newPath in the file system.**

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

The loading process is executed in a different thread and the loading is done asynchronously, so at the time you make the request the model is not yet loaded.

### Solution:

The solution is to request the information after it has been loaded that will be notified through the [`directoryLoaded`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#directoryLoaded) signal of [`QFileSystemModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html):

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QDir
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileSystemModel, QPushButton


class DemoB(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        self.model = QFileSystemModel(self)
        self.model.directoryLoaded.connect(self.on_directoryLoaded)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked(self):
        self.model.setRootPath(QDir.homePath())

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_directoryLoaded(self, directory):
        parentIndex = self.model.index(directory)
        for row in range(self.model.rowCount(parentIndex)):
            index = self.model.index(row, 0, parentIndex)
            print(index, index.data())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = DemoB()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```